# Combining 2 strings into one longer string in Assembly (.exe) - how does this code work?

Tags: assembly, concatenation, dos, x86-16

I received a code in Assembler that adds 2 strings together. Unfortunately I don't understand how this program works from lines 21 to 42. Could someone describe how this program works line by line in this area? Thank you!

```
                     .MODEL  SMALL
     
     Data           SEGMENT
     
     String1         DB      "It is our first string ",13,10,'$' 
     LENGTH_STRING1  EQU     23 
     String2         DB      "It is second string",13,10,'$'    
     LENGTH_STRING2  EQU     25 
     String3         DB      LENGTH_STRING1 + LENGTH_STRING2 DUP (?), 13, 10, '$'
     
     Data            ENDS
     
     Code             SEGMENT
     
                     ASSUME   CS:Code, DS:Data, SS:Bundle
     
     Start:
                     mov     ax, SEG Data               
                     mov     ds, ax
                    
  21                 mov     cx, LENGTH_STRING1         
  22                 mov     si, OFFSET String1     
  23                 mov     di, OFFSET String3     
  24               LOOP1:
  25                 mov     dl, [si]
  26                 mov     [di], dl
  27                 inc     si
  28                 inc     di
  29                 loop    LOOP1
  30                
  31                 mov     cx, LENGTH_STRING2         
  32                 mov     si, OFFSET String2
  33                LOOP2:
  34                 mov     dl, [si]               
  35                 mov     [di], dl             
  36                 inc     si
  37                 inc     di
  38                 loop    LOOP2
  39  
  40                 mov     ah, 09h                    
  41                 mov     dx, OFFSET String3     
  42                 int     21h
     
                     mov     ax, 4C00h              
                     int     21h
     
     Code         ENDS
     
     Bundle         SEGMENT STACK
     
                     DB      100h DUP (?)
     
     Bundle             ENDS
     
                     END Start
```

Comment: Which part is unclear? It just copies the first string then appends the second.

Comment: Why do we write for example mov si, OFFSET String1? The operation of the loop is not clear to me either (line 25-28).

Comment: That loads the address of the first character of `String1`. The loop simply processes each character one by one. Line 25 loads a character and 26 writes it out into `String3`. Then both pointers are incremented and the loop continues with the second character and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: FWIW, both of those LOOPs could be replaced with just `repz movsb`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  21                 mov     cx, LENGTH_STRING1         
  22                 mov     si, OFFSET String1     
  23                 mov     di, OFFSET String3
```

- Line 21 gets the length of `String1` into `cx`.
- Line 22 gets the pointer to `String1` (the first string) into `si`.
- Line 23 gets the pointer to `String3` (the free space) into `di`.

```
  24               LOOP1:
  25                 mov     dl, [si]
  26                 mov     [di], dl
  27                 inc     si
  28                 inc     di
  29                 loop    LOOP1
```

This is an inefficient, although valid, way to overwrite `String3` with the contents of `String1`. Since we loaded the pointer to `String1` into `si`, line 25 will read a byte from `String1` into `dl`, and then line 26 writes that byte to `String3`. Then we add 1 to `si` and `di` so that the next read and write both operate on the next letter of each. This process repeats until `cx = 0`, which is done by line 29.

This could have all been done however with `rep movsb`.

```
  31                 mov     cx, LENGTH_STRING2         
  32                 mov     si, OFFSET String2
```

Now, we need to copy string 2 into what remains of our free space. Thanks to our previous work, `di` is already in the right place, so we don't reload it. Instead we get `String2`'s length into `cx` and `String2`'s pointer into `si` and repeat this process with the next loop.

```
  40                 mov     ah, 09h                    
  41                 mov     dx, OFFSET String3     
  42                 int     21h
```

Finally this prints the string out to the screen.